# Nginx proxy_pass not normalising URL

Tags: nginx, configuration, reverse-proxy

I have the following config for an angular frontend on / and a node.js backend on /api/:

server {

```
    listen 80;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {

    root /home/ubuntu/www/admin;
    index index.html;


    expires -1;
    add_header Pragma "no-cache";
    add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-ch$

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;

    }


location /api/ {

proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
proxy_http_version      1.1;
proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection     'upgrade';
proxy_set_header        Host    $host;
proxy_cache_bypass      $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

}

This should be passing example.com/api/foo to 127.0.0.1:8080/foo, but is passing 127.0.0.1:8080//api/foo

I have looked through a lot of example configs and it would seem I am setting the trailing slashes correct, could anyone offer some advice?

Comment: This should work. Show full config

Comment: @AlexeyTen have updated the question

Comment: Are you sure, you get to this server block?

Comment: @AlexeyTen fairly certain, as the request gets passed to the server on 127.0.0.1:8080, only the request URL comes through prefixed with //api/

Answer (score 0):

It's working as intended exactly.

You forgot to rewrite the `/api` to `/`.

Try this:

```
location /api/ {
    rewrite ^/api(.*)$ /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Comment: PA's config shoud replace `/api/` with `/`, as pointed in nginx docs. Check http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass

Comment: According to the author it clearly doesn't. I'm providing a working solution.

Comment: It's better to find out the real reason (may be he just forgot to restart), before provide solution (not the best one)

Comment: Woow. Good luck then, you'll need it.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone encounters the same problem, I realised that the nginx in ubuntu's repos is not the full version of nginx. After adding the official PPA and reinstalling my config is now working as it should.